# javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb-3.1

I have found some same-title articles . Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for my error.

I'm new to JEE, JSF, EJB. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1. I'm following this guide: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevelopJavaEE6App.

This is:
 CustomerSessionBean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CustomerSessionBean {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Resource(name = "jms/NotificationQueue")
private Queue notificationQueue;
@Resource(name = "jms/NotificationQueueFactory")
private ConnectionFactory notificationQueueFactory;

public List<Customer> retrieve() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
    return query.getResultList();
}

public Customer update(Customer customer) {
    Customer updated = em.merge(customer);
    try {
        sendJMSMessageToNotificationQueue(updated);
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomerSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Customer updated in CustomerSessionBean!");
    return updated;
}

private Message createJMSMessageForjmsNotificationQueue(Session session, Object messageData) throws JMSException {

    ObjectMessage tm = session.createObjectMessage();
    tm.setObject((Serializable) messageData);
    return tm;
}

private void sendJMSMessageToNotificationQueue(Object messageData) throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        connection = notificationQueueFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(notificationQueue);
        messageProducer.send(createJMSMessageForjmsNotificationQueue(session, messageData));
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot close session", e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

public List<DiscountCode> getDiscountCodes() {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("DiscountCode.findAll");
    return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

I get this error: "javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB" every time I access a jsf page (In the guide: CustomerList.jsp; CustomerDetails.jsp) if I don't comment the "@Resource(name = "jms/NotificationQueue")". If I comment it, jsf page will display.

EDIT: this is stack trace:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:454)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2528)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at $Proxy226.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at com.customerapp.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__CustomerSessionBean__Intf____Bean__.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at com.customerapp.web.CustomerMBean.getCustomers(CustomerMBean.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1754)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:233)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:726)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
... 70 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Message-Destination-Ref jms/NotificationQueue@java.lang.String@null into class com.customerapp.ejb.CustomerSessionBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jms/NotificationQueue' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.SessionBean$1.inject(SessionBean.java:190)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:223)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1675)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:494)
... 74 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Message-Destination-Ref jms/NotificationQueue@java.lang.String@null into class com.customerapp.ejb.CustomerSessionBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jms/NotificationQueue' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:130)
... 79 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jms/NotificationQueue' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/jms/NotificationQueue [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
... 82 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/jms/NotificationQueue [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:242)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.WrappedSerialContext.getURLScheme(WrappedSerialContext.java:146)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.WrappedSerialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(WrappedSerialContext.java:103)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:82)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
... 87 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The JMS destination `jms/NotificationQueue` normally needs to be created. The guide indeed doesn't mention it.

Perhaps the Netbeans wizard creates it automatically for you and you haven't yet created the MDB via the wizard?

Edit:

The guide does mention it:

> - In the New Message-Driven Bean dialog, specify the EJB Name as
>     NotificationBean and the package as "com.customerapp.mdb", click on
>     the "Add..." button of the Project Destination option
> - In the Add Message Destination dialog, specify the Destination Name
>     as NotificationQueue and keep the Destination Type as Queue and click OK

This lets the Wizard create a `glassfish-resources.xml` file, that defines the queue:

```
<resources>
    <admin-object-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/NotificationQueue"  res-type="javax.jms.Queue"  res-adapter="jmsra">
        <property name="Name" value="PhysicalQueue"/>
    </admin-object-resource>
    <connector-connection-pool name="jms/NotificationQueueFactoryPool"  connection-definition-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"  resource-adapter-name="jmsra"/>
    <connector-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/NotificationQueueFactory" pool-name="jms/NotificationQueueFactoryPool"  />
</resources>
```

If you are not following the Guide to the letter and/or are not using Glassfish, you have to define this yourself (note that every Java EE implementation has a different syntax for this).

Comment: Thanks for answer me, 
 Mm.. I use Netbeans wizard to create NotificationBean (follow Netbeans guide).
 I checked Glassfish in Admin Console, JMS destination jms/NotificationQueue is created.

Comment: You might want to try deleting the needless xml files that the wizard creates in the EJB module: go to the Files view, then to CustomerApp-ejb -> src -> conf and delete the manifest and the glassfish-ejb.xml file (only peristence.xml should remain). Especially the glassfish-ejb.xml is totally unnecessary (since the EJB is already annotated) and can actually be harmful in this case.

Comment: p.s. I quickly followed the guide too, and here it just works.

Comment: I deleted manifest, I don't see any glassfish-ejb.xml. There is bean.xml instead. It's just still not running :(. Could you please zip your project and email me? (hainp2604@gmail.com). Thank you in advance

Comment: Jsf page will display if I change "@Resource(name = jms/NotificationQueue)" --> "@Resource(mappedName = "jms/NotificationQueue)", but Update function won't work.

Comment: Someone please help. Thank in advance :|

Answer (score 1):

Deleting of *glassfish-ejb-jar.xml* and Clean&Build helps in my case (Netbeans 7.1.1, glassfish 3.1.2)